# How can i add a property to my new class to decide on Form1 if to save the values or not to save?

Tags: c#

I want to be able in Form1 constructor for example to type: Options_DB.Save
Something like that or Options_DB.Save(true) or (false) 
So if its false the class will not take effect onl all the settings i did in Form1 according to Options_DB and if its true it will take effect and do all the things in the class Options_DB.

This is the class Options_DB:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using DannyGeneral;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace GatherLinks
{
    static class OptionsDB
    {
        static string changeWebsite;
        static bool downloadImages;
        static bool localOnly;
        static decimal num1;
        static string num1_numricupdown;
        static string path_exe;
        static string path_settings;
        static string settings_file;
        static string settings_dir;
        static OptionsFile setting_file;

        static OptionsDB()
        {
            path_exe = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath);

            path_settings = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.LocalUserAppDataPath);
            settings_file = "\\settings.txt";
            settings_dir = path_settings + @"\settings";
            setting_file = new OptionsFile(settings_dir + settings_file);

            // ---- L O A D I N G   A L L   K E Y S ---- \\

            changeWebsite = setting_file.GetKey("changeWebSite");
        }
        // ---- FUNCTIONS GET AND SET ---- \\

        public static string get_changedWebSite()
        {
            return changeWebsite;
        }

        public static void set_changeWebSite(string website)
        {
            changeWebsite = website;
            setting_file.SetKey("changeWebSite", changeWebsite);

        }
    }
}
```

And im using in it in Form1 for example like this:

In the Form1 constructor:

```
mainUrl =  OptionsDB.get_changedWebSite();
```

And in the button2 click event:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cl = new ChangeLink();
            cl.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
            DialogResult dr = cl.ShowDialog(this);
            if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                cl.Close();
            }
            else if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            {    
                    label4.Text = cl.getText();
                    mainUrl = cl.getText();
                    OptionsDB.set_changeWebSite(cl.getText());
                    cl.Close();
            } 


        }
```

Now in the Form1 constructor before im doing the Options_DB.get...
I want to add a property of the Options_DB or something that will tell me if to do the class the new class or not. This class im using a lot of time already to save on a text file all the options like checkBoxes and things so when i run the program it will remember the settings i changed.

Now i want a property that will tell the program of to save any changes i did or not to save them.

Comment: So basicly, you want an option to _turn on/off_ the use of `OptionsDB`?

Comment: And why can't you just add another property to the class? Or is that what you are asking how to do?

Comment: SH thats what im asking how to do if someone can show me how to do it.

Comment: SH i know how to add a property to the class but how do i make all the things i want to tunr if off/on for using the class. If ou clould show me what/how to do it in the class and also how to use it then in Form1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best I can do based on your question. It is hard to read/understand your question

```
private static bool isActive; // The new property; put it with the rest of the statics
public static string get_changedWebSite()
{
    return changeWebsite;
}

public static void set_changeWebSite(string website)
{
    if (isActive) // Check if it is active or not
    {
        changeWebsite = website;
        setting_file.SetKey("changeWebSite", changeWebsite);
    }
}

public bool IsActive // Get and set
{ 
  get
  {
     return isActive;
  } 
  set
  {
      isActive = value;
  } 
}
```

In `Form1` just write `OptionsDB.IsActive = false;` to turn off. `OptionsDB.IsActive = true;` to turn on. Possibly setting the initial value in the constuctur (`static OptionsDB()`).

Finally, you can really just change your get and set method to use **Accessors**. Like the Get and Set I used. **--Side advise; just because you can**

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right (but I'm not sure if I really understood what you're trying to do) you could simply add a public bool field to your Form1 class, create a constructor accepting a parm and setting it, and then check its value before accessing OptionsDB. Be careful that the field has to be set before accessing it. This means that you have to move the lines accessing OptionsDB in the new constructor and avoid using the default constructor.

Something like this (at least as a starting point):

```
    private bool useOptionsDB; 
    private Form1() // private to be sure you don't use it
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form1(bool useOptions)
        : this()
    {
        useOptionsDB = useOptions;
        // your stuff
        if (useOptionsDB)
            mainUrl = OptionsDB.get_changedWebSite();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cl = new ChangeLink();
        cl.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        DialogResult dr = cl.ShowDialog(this);
        if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            cl.Close();
        }
        else if (dr == DialogResult.OK && useOptionsDB) // <- add check on the bool field
        {
            label4.Text = cl.getText();
            mainUrl = cl.getText();
            OptionsDB.set_changeWebSite(cl.getText());
            cl.Close();
        }
    }
```